# while loop and variable not changing

Tags: while-loop

```
function test(num){
    var root1 = Math.sqrt(num);

    var ind=2;
    while(ind<=root1){
        if (ind%num==0 && IsPrime(ind)==true) {
            num=ind;
        }
        ind++;
        }
    return num;
}
```

Hi, in this code the function must return the largest prime factor of a given number, but the function returns the same number
For example: `test(123)` returns `123`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You want to check if `num` can be divided by `ind`, not the other way round. The test for that would be: `num % ind == 0`.
2. You should not re-use the `num` variable for the result. That way you overwrite the original number and the result will be wrong. Declare a new variable, for instance, `result`.

Comment: I add a `var result=0` in the function and changed the order in the remainder operator. :(  @Hellmar